# Helm chart Error can't evaluate field Values in type interface {} at .Values.agent.admin_group

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I having hard time looping over array values in values.yaml. The Error some kind of syntax/yaml structure related error but the message is so cryptic I have no idea what the issue is:
My values.yaml file:

```yaml
agent:
 namespace: "" <values are subject to change>
 enabled: true
 admin_group:
   - "TEST_GROUP_1"
   - "TEST_GROUP_2"
```

my template are:

```yaml
{{- if .Values.agent.enabled }}
kind: Rolebinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
subjects:
  {{- range .Values.agent.admin_group }}
  - kind: group
    apiGroup: rbac. authorization.k8s.io
    name: {{ .Values.agent.admin_group }}
  {{- end}}
roleRef:
  apigroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: view
{{- end -}}
```

I would also like to create multiple groups based on the array values of admin_group:

```yaml
{{- if .Values.agent.enabled }}
{{- range .Values.agent.admin_group }}
kind: Sync
apiVersion: group.xxx.com/v1alpha1
metadata:
  name: group-sync-{{ .Values.agent.namespace }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.agent.namespace }}
spec:
  domain: external
  group: {{ .Values.agent.admin_group }}
{{- end }}
{{- end -}}
```

Really appreciate the help. Happy Holidays!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with the *body* of your *range* loops. When you write this:

```
{{- range .Values.agent.admin_group }}
...
{{- end}}
```

Then you're redefining the meaning of `.`. Within the loop, `.` refers to each successive value produced by the `range` operator. When you write `.Values.agent.admin_group` *inside* the loop, you're getting an error because the list items don't have a `.Values` field (because they're strings). You want to write:

```
{{- range .Values.agent.admin_group }}
- kind: group
  apiGroup: rbac. authorization.k8s.io
  name: {{ . | quote }}
{{- end}}
```

And similarly in your `Sync` template.

You can find the relevant documentation [here](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#looping-with-the-range-action) which includes a number of examples (both on that page and on the subsequence page about variables).

Comment: Thank you @larsks. For Sync template how should i inject namespace name ??

Comment: You can reference `.Release.Namespace` if you want to use the Helm deployment namespace (the one you specify using `-n/--namespace` on the command line).